# Arista switch - getting chassis ID of currently logged in switch

Tags: switch, arista

I can not find how can i check local switch Chassis ID. [here](https://www.arista.com/en/um-eos/eos-section-18-3-lldp-configuration-procedures) i found that command:

```
show lldp local-info management 1
```

should show me what i want but there is no "local-info" option. Is there any other way to check it?

EDIT:

There is no mentioned options at all:

```
SW1(conf)#snmp-server ?
community               Enable SNMP; set community string       
contact                 Text for mib object sysContact          
context                 SNMP Context Name                       
enable                  Enable SNMP traps                       
engineID                Configure a local or remote SNMPv3 engineID
group                   Define a User Security Model group      
host                    Specify hosts to receive SNMP traps     
location                Text for mib object sysLocation         
packetsize              Set SNMP packet size                    
trap-source             Assign an interface for the source address of all traps
user                    Define a user who can access the SNMP engine
view                    Define an SNMPv2 MIB view               
vrf                     Specify vrf instance through which the SNMP should receive request (default vrf = 'default')

SW1#show lldp ?
neighbors               LLDP neighbors                          
statistics              Statistical information
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think “show lldp local-info management 1”, the MAC address will be displayed as the chassis ID. Try configuring the chassis ID with SNMP and see if it is displayed.

`switch(config)#snmp-server chassis-id chassis-sw1`
`switch(config)#show snmp`
`Chassis: chassis-sw1` <-- this is the chassis id

```
1631 SNMP packets input
   0 Bad SNMP version errors
    0 Unknown community name
    0 Illegal operation for community name supplied
    0 Encoding errors
    12 Number of requested variables
```

-- snip --

Comment: There is not such options, look on EDIT above. I checked management interface mac address and it is similar but not exactly same like ChassisID found on server and for sure this server is connected to that switch.

Comment: @user3069488 Did you enabled VRF? `show lldp ` result may be helpful.

Comment: like i wrote before there is no chassisId in show lldp statistics or neighbors option. Where to enable VRF? I do not see such possibility. What i find out on two other switches there is command "show lldp local-info management 1" but its not on two other, where i need to check it

Comment: @user3069488 What is the difference between the other two switches? Is the EoS version, model and LLDP enabled?

Comment: They are different one is:
System Type            : S6010-ON   
System Mode            : 1.0       
Software Version       : 9.11(0.0P8)

And second:
  Model                    Description                                         
  DCS-7050SX-64                               

  HW Version    
  ----------- -------------- ----------
  02.21
LLDP is anabled on both of them. On second one there is option with "local-info" on first not